# Dynamically building query for EF4 using expression trees, NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

I'm attempting to build an expression tree to perform a LINQ to Entities query in .NET 4.0 with EF4. When I attempt to execute the query I've built, I get a `NotSupportedException` with the following message:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[TestWpf.Customer]
>   Where(System.String, System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])' method,
>   and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I'm querying against the Northwind database. My entities were generated from the database. In my code below, I have the query I'm trying to build in the method `GetQuery1()`, and I'm attempting to build it in the `GetQuery2()` method.

If I set a breakpoint and inspect the `query1` variable, it's `Expression` property is:

```
Convert(value(System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[TestWpf.Customer])).MergeAs(AppendOnly).Where(c => c.CompanyName.Contains("z"))
```

What is this `Convert().MergeAs(AppendOnly)` doing? I attempted to search on MSDN but couldn't locate what I need (at least I don't think I could find it...). Additionally, what am I doing wrong?

I think that perhaps I'm calling an incorrect `Where()` method, as Intellisense says there is another, which is an extension method. I have not tried to update the `whereMethod` variable to fetch that one, but I'm not sure how, either.

```
private static IQueryable<Customer> GetQuery1(NorthEntities context) {
    return context.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.Contains("z"));
}

private static IQueryable<Customer> GetQuery2(NorthEntities context) {
    var custParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "c");
    var custCollection = Expression.Constant(context.Customers);
    var companyNamePropValue = Expression.Property(custParam, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("CompanyName"));
    var containsParameter = Expression.Constant("z");
    var containsMethod = Expression.Call(companyNamePropValue, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), containsParameter);
    var whereMethod = context.Customers.GetType().GetMethod("Where", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(ObjectParameter[]) });
    var param2 = Expression.Constant(new ObjectParameter[] { });
    var where = Expression.Call(custCollection, whereMethod, companyNamePropValue, param2);
    return ((IQueryable<Customer>)context.Customers).Provider.CreateQuery<Customer>(where);
}

private static void Main(string[] args) {
    using (var context = new NorthEntities()) {
        var query1 = GetQuery1(context);
        var query2 = GetQuery2(context);

        foreach (var c in query1)
            Console.WriteLine(c.CompanyName);
        foreach (var c in query2)
            Console.WriteLine(c.CompanyName);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To construct the specific query you're working with, try the following:

```
private static IQueryable<Customer> GetQuery2(NorthEntities context) {
    IQueryable<Customer> customers = context.Customers;
    var custParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Customer), "c");
    var companyNamePropValue = Expression.Property(custParam, typeof(Customer).GetProperty("CompanyName"));
    var containsParameter = Expression.Constant("z");
    var containsCall = Expression.Call(companyNamePropValue, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), containsParameter);
    var wherePredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Customer, bool>>(containsCall, custParam);
    return customers.Where(wherePredicate);
}
```

In general, to get access to the LINQ extension methods (e. g. Where), you'll have to look in the `Queryable` class:

```
var genericWhereMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
    .Single(m => m.Name == "Where" 
        // distinguishes between Where((T, int) => bool) and Where(T => bool)
        && m.GetParameters()[1].ParameterType
           .GetGenericArguments()[0].GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Func<,>));

// make the Where method that applies to IQueryable<Customer>
var whereMethod = genericWhereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Customer));
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you. I've also determined that I don't need to include the `Where()` call in my tree, just the conditionals. First time working with them, and boy are they confusing!